# How to apply CSS to the input fields of only one react component?

Tags: input

I am trying to apply CSS to the input fields of a react component. I have written CSS in a correspondent CSS file of a component but It is applied to input fields of other components. What can I do to apply the input field styles only for the component that I want? [In the image below I have shown the code of CSS input fields of a single component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuApv.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, make sure your CSS file name is `fileName.module.css`:

   ```
   style.module.css
   ```
2. Write your CSS attributes:

   ```css
   .test{color:red;}
   ```
3. Import your CSS file into your React component:

   ```
   import styles from './style.module.css'
   ```
4. Apply the style:

   ```
   <h1 className={styles.test}>This is test text.</h1>
   ```

Done!